# Chart.js Axis Label Tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js within a grid system for a project.

The grid system allows users to make relatively small charts.

In this situation we truncate the axis labels based on fixed breakpoints against the grid size for that axis.

However as a requirement for this work the user needs to be presented with a tooltip when hovering over the truncated axis label.

Is this at all possible with Chart.JS? Either naitively or through a plugin?

I'm assuming if hooks are available ill have to use a callback method, like with data-points, to get the un-truncated label.

Ive looked through the documentation on Tooltips and couldn't find anything for Axis label tooltips.

**To clarify**

Is it possible for Chart.Js to show a tooltip just for the Axis Labels independently to tooltips shown when hovering over a data-point?

In the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/692hkmwf/1/) the YAxis label has been truncated as it is too long for the space. (This would be done pragmatically by my code in production). What i would like is for Chart.js to render a tooltip when the user hovers over that axis label and provide it with the full un-truncated label.

Ive seen the following option block, however it mentions nothing in the docs about tooltips for this option. I'm beginning to fear its not possible. Just after confirmation or not of that really.

```
  scaleLabel: {
    display: true,
    labelString: 'Some Axis...'
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a fiddle out of your problem ? A small-sized canvas element could make one of your small charts

Comment: @tektiv i can, however I'm not entirely sure how it would help. I'm not asking for bug support or `why isn't this working`. Its more of a `Can Chart.JS do this` sort of question. In this case can Chart.Js show a tooltip just for the Axis Labels, as it does when hovering over a data point. However if a fiddle will help to represent that, then ill provide one.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I need to do something similar.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this.  Did anybody manage to get this done?

Comment: I never did, we ended up changing product requirements. However this is two years old now, maybe newer versions of Chart.JS have this ability?